# How to prevent sgmf-scripts to scratch sensitive files?

Tags: commerce-cloud

Right now I’m developing a SFCC Commerce Cloud website.
Referring to SFRA recommendations, I’m using the `sgmf-scripts` command to create, compile and upload custom cartridges.

The problem is, each time I create a cartridge, `sgmf-scripts` is scratching sensitive files such as `dw.json`, `package.json` or `webpack.config.js`, which is pretty annoying.

Does anyone know how to avoid this behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well have you tried to protect the files in question with the means of your operating system? You set files to read-only in Windows via Properties, or use Terminal in UNIX systems (Linux/MacOS) with `$ chmod go-w data.txt`